# paragraph Select() doesn't work in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html code

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display: none">
  <p id="para">Copy this key</p>
    <p id="key">4567887654345678</p>
</div>

<button>Open dialog</button>
```

The div appears as a dialog on button click, and I would like to have the

"key" text selected when the dialog opens

Here is the javascript for the same, but the < p> doesn't appear to be selected

```
$(function() {
    $( "button" ).click(function() {
      $("#dialog" ).dialog();
        $( "#dialog" ).show( "slow" );        
        $("#key").select();
  });
    });
```

How can I make the < p> be pre-selected ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `key` paragraph to an editable element, such as a textarea:

```
<textarea id="key">4567887654345678</textarea>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfym4xq7/2/)

It appears you need an editable text field to select text in.

Comment: Thank you. But it should appear like a paragraph ! With input, you don't get multiline flexibility, the cancel icon appears etc.

Comment: @user2837167 I changed it to a *textarea* element so you can have multilines, made it *readonly*, and added some css styling to take off the borders and handle. I don't know any other way to dynamically select text so it can be copied to the clipboard. See the updated JSFiddle in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [jQuery dialog open event](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open):

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#key").select();
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqLjsgt7/)